# Is it necessary to enable default-ssl in apache2

Tags: apache2

my localhost/cgi-bin is not working. I just want to know that, is it necessary to enable default-ssl for cgi configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe default-ssl is only the configuration for SSL Enabled Websites. So, it must not be necessary for cgi-bin.

You could try locating the path needed to access your cgi-bin in default, under DocumentRoot /cgi-bin section.